# How to change color style attribut with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

This code doesn't work when I try it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1 >My first java script</h1>
<p id="p2">I can change color by one click</p>
</br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementsById("p2").style.color = "yellow";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementsById("p2").style.color = "yellow";
}
```

```html
<h1>My first java script</h1>
<p id="p2">I can change color by one click</p>
</br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: You just have a typo: it's `getElementById`, singular, not "elements".

Comment: You misspelled `getElementsById`, should be `getElementById`

Comment: Further to the other comments it's worth taking a look in the developer console (F12, in most browsers) as that would have pointed out that there is `getElementsById` function.

Comment: Simple debugging skills required.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is getElementById without s.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1 >My first java script</h1>
<p id="p2">I can change color by one click</p>
</br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "yellow";
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("p2").style.color = "yellow";
}
```

```html
<h1>My first java script</h1>
<p id="p2">I can change color by one click</p>
</br>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: We don't post answer for typo's, we close it (there is an option for it under "Close")

Comment: When there is a typo in a question, one comment and vote to close, one does not answer such question ... so I downvote you for not following SO policy

Comment: @MohammedBadr We don't accept answers when there is a typo in your question. Read SO policy to know how to act.